# "songs" package, chord size

Tags: fontsize, songs

I am trying to write an A6 songbook in latex(just getting started).
For chords above lyrics I use the [`songs`](http://songs.sourceforge.net/) package, but the chords looks bigger than the lyrics.

Can't find anything in the documentation on how to make the text for the chords smaller.
Annyone know how?

A minimal working example showing the default settings:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[chorded]{songs}

\newindex{titleidx}{titleidx}
\noversenumbers

\begin{document}
\showindex{Complete Index of Songs}{titleidx}
\songsection{Worship Songs}

\begin{songs}{titleidx}
\beginsong{Doxology}[by={Louis Bourgeois and Thomas Ken},
                     sr={Revelation 5:13},
                     cr={Public domain.},
                     index={Praise God, from Whom all blessings flow}]
\beginverse
\[G]Praise God, \[D]from \[Em]Whom \[Bm]all \[Em]bless\[D]ings \[G]flow;
\[G]Praise Him, all \[D]crea\[Em]tures \[C]here \[G]be\[D]low;
\[Em]Praise \[D]Him \[G]a\[D]bove, \[G]ye \[C]heav'n\[D]ly \[Em]host;
\[G]Praise Fa\[Em]ther, \[D]Son, \[Am]and \[G/B G/C]Ho\[D]ly \[G]Ghost.
\[C]A\[G]men.
\endverse
\endsong
\end{songs}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Could you provide a minimal working example, i.e. from `\documentclass{` to `\end{document}`? I'm a bit lost as to what text exactly you want to make smaller, and an MWE will help in answering your question.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436)

Comment: I added a MWE and uploaded the resulting image. I hope it's OK.

Answer (score 5):

The command controlling how chords are typeset is `\printchord` and its default definition is

```
\renewcommand\printchord[1]{\sffamily\slshape\large#1}
```

You can redefine it according to your needs; a simple example to use `\small` instead of the default `\large` size switch (of course, you can use any of the other font switches or even `\fontsize{}{}\selectfont` instead):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[chorded]{songs}

\newindex{titleidx}{titleidx}
\noversenumbers

\renewcommand\printchord[1]{\sffamily\slshape\small#1}

\begin{document}
\showindex{Complete Index of Songs}{titleidx}
\songsection{Worship Songs}

\begin{songs}{titleidx}
\beginsong{Doxology}[by={Louis Bourgeois and Thomas Ken},
                     sr={Revelation 5:13},
                     cr={Public domain.},
                     index={Praise God, from Whom all blessings flow}]
\beginverse
\[G]Praise God, \[D]from \[Em]Whom \[Bm]all \[Em]bless\[D]ings \[G]flow;
\[G]Praise Him, all \[D]crea\[Em]tures \[C]here \[G]be\[D]low;
\[Em]Praise \[D]Him \[G]a\[D]bove, \[G]ye \[C]heav'n\[D]ly \[Em]host;
\[G]Praise Fa\[Em]ther, \[D]Son, \[Am]and \[G/B G/C]Ho\[D]ly \[G]Ghost.
\[C]A\[G]men.
\endverse
\endsong
\end{songs}

\end{document}
```

[image]

The `songs` package is not on CTAN; it can be found in [`sourceforge`](http://songs.sourceforge.net/)

Comment: Is `songs` part of CTAN? Tex Live Utility can't seem to find it...

Comment: @Jubobs: If I'm not mistaken, `songs` used to be part of CTAN, but the version was quite outdated. The package is now available in its own [SourceForge website](http://songs.sourceforge.net/).

Comment: @Jubobs Paulo is right; I added the link in my answer.

Comment: Ok, this is good solution.
But I have another question: it's possible change the font of chords?
Like Garamond font for lyrics and CM for chords?